Subtract values from columns based on sequence and create results in new columns
I need to subtract a sequence of values ​​from 0 to 20 from a data frame column.
In the example below I have daily temperatures and I need to create a sequence of columns with the subtractions.
temp <- c(26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 27, 28, 29)
date <- as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-16-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-18-2021', 
                  '02-19-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-21-2021', '02-22-2021'), 
                "%m-%d-%Y")
A <- data.frame(date, temp)
head(A)
B <- seq(0.5, 20, 0.5)

A$temp - B #I tried it

I want to subtract the values ​​of each row from the temp column in sequence and generate columns with the results.
The result I expect is the following:


You want using sapply. If you setNames B with B you easily get the  column names. The cbind is necessary to not to overwrite the old "temp" column.
> transform(A, temp=cbind(temp, sapply(setNames(B, B), \(b) temp - b)))
        date temp.temp temp.0.5 temp.1 temp.1.5 temp.2 temp.2.5 temp.3 temp.3.5 temp.4 temp.4.5 temp.5
1 2021-02-15      26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0     22.5   22.0     21.5   21.0
2 2021-02-16      27.0     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0     22.5   22.0
3 2021-02-17      28.0     27.5   27.0     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0
4 2021-02-18      30.0     29.5   29.0     28.5   28.0     27.5   27.0     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0
5 2021-02-19      32.0     31.5   31.0     30.5   30.0     29.5   29.0     28.5   28.0     27.5   27.0
6 2021-02-20      27.0     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0     22.5   22.0
7 2021-02-21      28.0     27.5   27.0     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0
8 2021-02-22      29.0     28.5   28.0     27.5   27.0     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0
  temp.5.5 temp.6 temp.6.5 temp.7 temp.7.5 temp.8 temp.8.5 temp.9 temp.9.5 temp.10 temp.10.5 temp.11
1     20.5   20.0     19.5   19.0     18.5   18.0     17.5   17.0     16.5    16.0      15.5    15.0
2     21.5   21.0     20.5   20.0     19.5   19.0     18.5   18.0     17.5    17.0      16.5    16.0
3     22.5   22.0     21.5   21.0     20.5   20.0     19.5   19.0     18.5    18.0      17.5    17.0
4     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0     22.5   22.0     21.5   21.0     20.5    20.0      19.5    19.0
5     26.5   26.0     25.5   25.0     24.5   24.0     23.5   23.0     22.5    22.0      21.5    21.0
6     21.5   21.0     20.5   20.0     19.5   19.0     18.5   18.0     17.5    17.0      16.5    16.0
7     22.5   22.0     21.5   21.0     20.5   20.0     19.5   19.0     18.5    18.0      17.5    17.0
8     23.5   23.0     22.5   22.0     21.5   21.0     20.5   20.0     19.5    19.0      18.5    18.0
  temp.11.5 temp.12 temp.12.5 temp.13 temp.13.5 temp.14 temp.14.5 temp.15 temp.15.5 temp.16 temp.16.5
1      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5    12.0      11.5    11.0      10.5    10.0       9.5
2      15.5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5    12.0      11.5    11.0      10.5
3      16.5    16.0      15.5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5    12.0      11.5
4      18.5    18.0      17.5    17.0      16.5    16.0      15.5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5
5      20.5    20.0      19.5    19.0      18.5    18.0      17.5    17.0      16.5    16.0      15.5
6      15.5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5    12.0      11.5    11.0      10.5
7      16.5    16.0      15.5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5    12.0      11.5
8      17.5    17.0      16.5    16.0      15.5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5
  temp.17 temp.17.5 temp.18 temp.18.5 temp.19 temp.19.5 temp.20
1     9.0       8.5     8.0       7.5     7.0       6.5     6.0
2    10.0       9.5     9.0       8.5     8.0       7.5     7.0
3    11.0      10.5    10.0       9.5     9.0       8.5     8.0
4    13.0      12.5    12.0      11.5    11.0      10.5    10.0
5    15.0      14.5    14.0      13.5    13.0      12.5    12.0
6    10.0       9.5     9.0       8.5     8.0       7.5     7.0
7    11.0      10.5    10.0       9.5     9.0       8.5     8.0
8    12.0      11.5    11.0      10.5    10.0       9.5     9.0


df <- data.frame(
data = as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-16-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-19-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-21-2021',
                  '02-22-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y"),
temp = c(26,27,28,30,32,27,28,29))

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

diffs <- seq(0.5,20,0.5)

temp_cols <- diffs |>
  map(\(x) df$temp - x)

names(temp_cols) <- paste0("temp",diffs)

bind_cols(df, temp_cols |> bind_cols())
#>         data temp temp0.5 temp1 temp1.5 temp2 temp2.5 temp3 temp3.5 temp4
#> 1 2021-02-15   26    25.5    25    24.5    24    23.5    23    22.5    22
#> 2 2021-02-16   27    26.5    26    25.5    25    24.5    24    23.5    23
#> 3 2021-02-17   28    27.5    27    26.5    26    25.5    25    24.5    24
#> 4 2021-02-18   30    29.5    29    28.5    28    27.5    27    26.5    26
#> 5 2021-02-19   32    31.5    31    30.5    30    29.5    29    28.5    28
#> 6 2021-02-20   27    26.5    26    25.5    25    24.5    24    23.5    23
#> 7 2021-02-21   28    27.5    27    26.5    26    25.5    25    24.5    24
#> 8 2021-02-22   29    28.5    28    27.5    27    26.5    26    25.5    25

Created on 2024-06-03 with reprex v2.1.0
